# Traceroute to IP address fails, but traceroute to domain name with same IP address is okay. Why?

Tags: networking, dns, traceroute, icmp

When I traceroute to this IP (108.162.198.181) it stops after 1 hop. But tracerouting to a domain (www.gomodule.com) with the same IP shows 9 hops ending in that target.

```
traceroute to www.gomodule.com (108.162.198.81), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  131.667 ms  48.532 ms  48.837 ms
 2  118.69.255.124 (118.69.255.124)  91.521 ms  79.177 ms  30.679 ms
 3  42.117.11.225 (42.117.11.225)  30.270 ms  32.091 ms  29.698 ms
 4  118.69.253.213 (118.69.253.213)  32.234 ms
    118.69.253.237 (118.69.253.237)  70.667 ms
    118.69.253.213 (118.69.253.213)  82.440 ms
 5  118.69.253.245 (118.69.253.245)  64.554 ms  80.277 ms  130.224 ms
 6  118.69.251.205 (118.69.251.205)  65.635 ms
    118.69.249.78 (118.69.249.78)  133.234 ms
    118.69.251.205 (118.69.251.205)  224.111 ms
 7  118.69.251.249 (118.69.251.249)  156.679 ms  111.965 ms  64.165 ms
 8  cloudflare1-rge.hkix.net (202.40.160.246)  64.102 ms  64.498 ms  74.581 ms
 9  108.162.198.81 (108.162.198.81)  66.873 ms  67.426 ms  69.054 ms
```

-vs-

```
traceroute to 108.162.198.181 (108.162.198.181), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  96.588 ms  3.003 ms  4.976 ms
 2  118.69.255.124 (118.69.255.124)  45.223 ms  31.449 ms  31.225 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
108.162.198.181
```

as compared to

```
108.162.198.81
          ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your IP address. They are different in both the cases.